# Excel VBA macro to select data based on date and move it to a new tab

Tags: vba, excel, subtotal

I am hoping you can help me.  I'm not great at vba and your community has been a great help in the past.   I have to, on a monthly basis, run a report showing hours that are worked for my team on a a consulting project.  Screen print attached
[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAuPb.png)

there are about 1,000 rows and I  need to move rows with the same date in the week ending field to a new tab.   in the example above the result would be the data copied to two tabs with 3/23 records on one sheet and 3/30 on another.     I have found macro samples that will copy data based on input, but not that are the same and the report updates quarterly with 9 different weeks listed.   This will give me a good start

Comment: You should edit your question down to the things that someone would need to answer your question. How many columns does the report have? What col has the target dates in question? A lot of unnecessary information here. Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: thanks for the feedback- Spreadsheet has 16 columns the column titled "week ending" has the data.  example spreadsheet has  PROJECT, HOURS, CONSULTANT, WEEK ENDING.    I need all rows with the same week ending date moved to another tab so if there are 4 different values in the week ending field I end up with 4 tabs with the values on each tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TransferReport()

'Check each date
 For Each DateEnd In Sheet15.Columns(4).Cells    'Change Sheet15 refer to your report tab
    If DateEnd.Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'Stop program if no date
    If IsDate(DateEnd.Value) Then
        shtName = Format(DateEnd.Value, "dd.mm")    'Change date to valid tab name

        On Error GoTo errorhandler  'if no Date Sheet, go to errorhandler to create new tab
        If Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
           DateEnd.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2")
           Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1:J1").Columns.AutoFit
        Else
            DateEnd.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
Next

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create new tab
ActiveSheet.Name = shtName  'Name tab with date
Sheet15.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'Copy heading to new tab
Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you!  only one question - how do I get the formatting & column width of the new tabs to be the same as the source tabs?

Comment: Autofit column to fit text length.